# how to prompt user to download app when connected to bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am looking for an easy way to prompt a user to download app from android (or iOS) when using external accessory/device.

I have a bluetooth device, and would like to prompt user when that device is connected for the first time to a phone. Has someone found a trick to do such a thing?

I believe this is possible with USB connection to phone using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED

Any idea when connecting bluetooth classic or smart?